# IF conditional evaluates variable into range, BASH

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

Good day to all,

I was wondering how to evaluate a string variable into a range, is it possible?

```
 S=CUESTIONARIO15 ; if [ "$S" == "${S:0:12}*[0-9][0-9]*" ] ;then echo 999 ;fi
```

Thanks so much in advance for any clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match against globs using `[[`:

```
S=CUESTIONARIO15
if [[ "$S" == "${S:0:12}"*[0-9][0-9]* ]]
then
  echo 999
fi
```

Make sure to use bash and not sh, and make sure not to quote the globbing characters in the pattern.